# Plotting in a consistent manner across platforms

Tags: r

I decided it was important for R users to be able to play hangman and made an R hangman game.  The problem is I don't do many plots for general release and so I don't know how to provide the user with a plot that works independent of platform or gui.

Here's where you can download the complete package that contains large word bank:

```
library(devtools); install_github("hangman", "trinker")
```

The function that plots looks like this (I made the word bank go away for reproducibility):

```
hangman <- function() {
        #x1 <- DICTIONARY[sample(1:nrow(DICTIONARY), 1), 1]
        x1 <- "trapped"
        x <- unlist(strsplit(x1, NULL))
        len <- length(x)
        x2 <- rep("_", len)
        chance <- 0
        win1 <- 0
        win <- win1/len
        wrong <- character()
        right <- character()
        print(x2, quote = FALSE)
        hang.plot <- function(){ #plotting function
                plot.new()
                mtext("HANGMAN", col = "blue", cex=2)    
                mtext(paste(x2, collapse = " "), side = 1, cex=1.5) 
                mtext("wrong", side = 3, cex=1.5,
                          adj = 0, padj = 5, col = "red") 
                text(.015, .8, paste(wrong, collapse = "\n"), offset=.3, 
                         cex=1.5, adj=c(0,1))
                mtext("correct", side = 3, cex=1.5,
                          adj = 1, padj = 5, col = "red")
                text(.96, .8, paste(right, collapse = "\n"), offset=.3, 
                         cex=1.5, adj=c(0,1))
                segments(.365, .77, .365, .83, lwd=2)
                segments(.365, .83, .625, .83, lwd=2)
                segments(.625, .83, .625, .25, lwd=2)
                segments(.57, .25, .675, .25, lwd=2)
                parts <- seq_len(length(wrong))
                if (identical(wrong, character(0))) {
                        parts <- 0
                }
                if (1 %in% parts) {
                        mtext("O", side = 1, cex=4, adj = .365, padj = -7.2)
                        mtext("o o", side = 1, cex=1, adj = .3725, padj = -28.2)
                        mtext("<", side = 1, cex=1, adj = .373, padj = -27.6)
                        mtext("__", side = 1, cex=1, adj = .373, padj = -27.2)
                }
                if (2 %in% parts) {
                        mtext("I", side = 1, cex=4, adj = .375, padj = -6.25)
                        mtext("I", side = 1, cex=4, adj = .375, padj = -5.5)
                        mtext("I", side = 1, cex=4, adj = .375, padj = -4.75)
                }
                if (3 %in% parts) {
                        segments(.37, .57, .45, .63, lwd=7)
                }
                if (4 %in% parts) {
                        segments(.37, .57, .29, .63, lwd=7)
                }
                if (5 %in% parts) {
                        segments(.37, .426, .43, .3, lwd=7)
                        mtext("__", side = 1, cex = 1, adj = .373, 
                                  padj = -27.2, col = "white")
                        mtext("O", side = 1, cex = 1.25, adj = .373, padj = -21.5, 
                                  col="red")
                }
                if (6 %in% parts) {
                        segments(.37, .426, .31, .3, lwd = 7)
                        mtext("o o", side = 1, cex = 1, adj = .3725, 
                                  padj = -28.2, col="white")
                        mtext("x x", side = 1, cex=1, adj = .3725, padj = -28.2)
                        mtext("You Lose", side = 1, cex=8, padj = -3, 
                                  col = "darkgreen")
                        mtext(paste(x2, collapse = " "), side = 1, cex=1.6, col="white") 
                        mtext(paste(x2, collapse = " "), side = 1, cex=1.5, col="white") 
                        mtext(paste(x2, collapse = " "), side = 1, adj = .51, cex=1.6, 
                                  col="white")
                        mtext(paste(x, collapse = " "), side = 1, cex=1.5)
                }
                if (win1 == len) {
                        mtext("WINNER!", side = 1, cex=8, padj = -3, 
                                  col = "green")
                        mtext("WINNER!", side = 1, cex=8, adj = .1, padj = -3.1, 
                                  col = "darkgreen")
                }
        } #end of hang.plot
        guess <- function(){#start of guess function
                cat("\n","Choose a letter:","\n") 
                y <- scan(n=1,what = character(0),quiet=T)
                if (y %in% c(right, wrong)) {
                        stop(paste0("You've already guessed ", y))
                }
                if (!y %in% letters) {
                        stop(paste0(y, " is not a letter"))
                }
                if (y %in% x) {
                        right <<- c(right, y)
                        win1 <<- sum(win1, sum(x %in% y)) 
                        win <<- win1/len 
                        message(paste0("Correct!","\n"))
                } else {
                        wrong  <<- c(wrong, y)
                        chance  <<- length(wrong)
                        message(paste0("The word does not contain ", y, "\n"))
                }
                x2[x %in% right] <<- x[x %in% right]
                print(x2, quote = FALSE)
                hang.plot()
        }#end of guess function
        hang.plot()
        while(all(win1 != len & chance < 6)){ 
                try(guess())
        } 
        if (win == 1) {
                outcome <- "\nCongratulations! You Win!\n"
        } else {
                outcome <- paste("\nSorry. You loose. The word is:", x1, "\n")
        }
        cat(outcome)
}
```

This looks great on RGUI (in windows) where I created it but the plot is misconfigured in RStudio.  How can I make the code plot everything in a way that lines up/looks good independent of gui/platform (my friend bryangoodrich suggested grid as a possibility)?

Comment: Just can't resist saying that's one of the oddest homonymic errors I've seen in a while :-)

Comment: OK, srsly, my guess is that RStudio is assuming different default spatial units for its graph window.  Perhaps a couple calls to `par` specifying the axis and text size units will solve the problem?

Comment: Perhaps it's not an error and more of a comentary on the player's promiscuity :)

Comment: I found an [inconsistently maintained manor](http://cityofbyroncity.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/3309167358_eb6f1d475e.jpg) for you.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: So there were two errors I suppose the loose error was not what Carl was referring to :)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman How do you know there is any plotting happening in that manor?

Comment: I found you a manor where some plotting happened, but it looks well maintained: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donington_le_Heath_Manor_House_Museum

Comment: @Andrie there's clearly nothing happening on the manor's plot.

Comment: I don't have RGUI here, so what's the value of `par("las")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `text()` instead of `mtext()`. All coordinate must be reconsider. Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on Alan's answer, if you insist on drawing the head as the letter "O", then you'll need to calculate the height of the character, and use `text` instead of `mtext`. For example, this works in both rgui and in RStudio (on Windows) to attach the head to the first `segment`

```
plot.new()
segments(0.365, 0.77, 0.365, 0.83, lwd = 2)
text(0.365,0.77-strheight("O", cex=4)/2,"O", cex=4)
```

Resizing doesn't work, but you get the idea.

Comment: I tested this and think it will work.  I may go with plotting a circle but thought it difficult.  Thanks to [John Fox](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/04/25821.html) it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I think both answers certainly led to the solution which was to remove all `mtext` and replace with text, circles and segments.  Thank you much +1  To play use: `library(devtools); install_github("hangman", "trinker")`